# EF Core TPH entities with same required property type cause "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint" exception

Tags: .net, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core

I have two classes that are derived from the same base class and have the same required property. They are in the same table (TPH).

When I try to create the DB I get this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Introducing FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint 'FK_As_Bs_A2BId' on table 'As' may cause cycles or multiple
>   cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or
>   modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or
>   index. See previous errors.

```cs
public class Entity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class A : Entity { }

public class A1 : A
{
    [Required]
    public B A1B { get; set; }
}

public class A2 : A
{
    [Required]
    public B A2B { get; set; }
}

public class B : Entity { }

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<A1> A1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<A2> A2s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class CreateDbTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CreateDb()
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("YOURCONNECTIONSTRING");
        using (var context = new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
        {
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain the problem to me? I don't get it. Would almost think this is a bug.
The problem only occures when both entities' property have the required attribute and both are in the same table (TBH). There is no problem when A1 and A2 get their own tables (by not adding `DbSet<A>`).

Comment: The more I think about it the more it feels like a bug to me. So I [created an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15077).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug, but SqlServer (and some other) database limitation. It happens when one table has more than one cascade FK relationships with another table.

In your case it's caused by the TPH, but the same will happen if you have

```
public class C : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public B C1B { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public B C2B { get; set; }
}
```

TPH uses single table to store all derived entities, hence has all single table imposed FK relationship limitations.

To resolve the issue in both cases, you need to break the "cascade" part of the "multiple cascade paths" by turning off the cascade delete for at least one of the involved relationships and handle deletion manually or via database trigger.